# link external stylesheet conflicting with script src loading jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, conflict

Hi I was doing a simple expanding slider with *jquery* 
and somehow the slider would expand to the full-width
of the window, then shrink to the desired width I assigned it to do ..

**(if you reload the page a few times, it comes up sometimes)**

the problem seems to disappear switch the loading order 
of the  and  between *jquery* and my *external stylesheet*

but I am not sure why, I am wondering if anyone knows ????

here is the code that's causing the problem

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider").animate({width:'100px'},1300);
});
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="slider">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
#slider{
width:10px;
height:20px;
background:#09C; 
}
```

after switch the order of  and 
the expanding issue disappear:

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link type="text/css" href="screen.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider").animate({width:'100px'},1300);
});
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="slider">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
#slider{
width:10px;
height:20px;
background:#09C; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because scripts should always be loaded after static assets?

Most browsers render line by line from top to bottom so a change made on one line can be changed again on the next line.

If one loads the script first then the style will change the script.